# Syntax Error in Python Request Library when Using on My Test server

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, python-requests, django-wsgi

I'm using Python Request Library in one of my projects. Everything works fine on my local system where I have Python 2.6 and Django 1.2.3.

I have created the same environment for my Test server(Python 2.6 and Django 1.2.3 and is using WSGI 3.2). Now I get some weird syntax errors. For example:

```
line 266
    result.append((k.encode('utf-8') if isinstance(k, unicode) else k,
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*
```

Here's another:

```
from .config import settings
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*
```

I'm guessing it's something because of wsgi but not sure exactly. Can someone please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your webserver (such as apache) is using an older version of python, rather than the python 2.6 environment you setup.

Comment: Thanks...that was the Issue. I was using Webfaction and they had two Versions of Python.

Answer (score 1):

This errors mean that actually you are not using Python 2.6.  Probably Python 2.4 is also installed on you environment and it is used to execute your code.

Comment: Thanks...that was the issue. I am using Webfaction and they have 2 versions of Python Installed